# Search with multiple parameters in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

This question is related to both c# and SQL Server.

I want to figure out how to do a custom search.

I have three tables

**Customer**

```
CusId, Name, Telephone
```

**Employee**

```
EmpId, Name, Job
```

**Appointment**

```
AppId, Date, EmpId, CusId
```

My C# form has three checkboxes. I want to find the data according to those checked values.

Ex: when customer,employee,app check boxes have selected, I want to find data on depending on all those three values.

When only two or one is selected I want to search depending on those selection. Here there will be total 6 combinations.

How to write a query to get correct result when I pass those values as parameters to a stored procedure.

Do I have to write 6 stored procedures to get the result?

Are there any methods to do this easily?

Please help me to fix this matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried already, how are you accessing the database from C# (entity framework, ADO.NET ...), can you use stored procedures, are you composing a text query (with parameters to prevent SQL injection)? All this may change the answer, so telling us what you have tried will help answer the question.

Comment: If you use EF, this is trivial. If you don't, it's still easy but requires more code. How do you access the DB ? On a side note, 3 options make for 8 combinations, not 6

Comment: Yep i am using EF. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a query such as the below (would suggest in a stored proc):

```
-- Parameters to a SQL sproc
DECLARE @CustID INT, @EmpID INT, @AppointmentID INT

-- Set Parameters here for testing

SELECT *
FROM Appointment as A
INNER JOIN Employee as E
  ON E.EmpID = A.EmpId
INNER JOIN Customer as C
  ON C.CusID = A.CusID
WHERE (@CustID IS NULL OR C.CUsID = @CustID)
AND (@EmpID IS NULL OR E.EmpID = @EmpID)
AND (@AppointmentID IS NULL OR A.AppID = @AppointmentID)
```

You then need to pass in the parameters appropriately, either an ID if selected, or null if not filtering on one item.